# T-SQL OpenRowSet from CSV missing header row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

I have a CSV that doesn't have a HEADER row.  Using OpenRowSet assumes the first row is the HEADER row.  How do I prevent this from happening? I know there are 18,000 records in my CSV file, but when I open with OpenRowSet, I only get 17,999, and the first row in the CSV is labeled as the column headers.

TIA

Comment: Try adding `;HDR=NO` to the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

add the `firstrow` option for [openrowset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

for example:

```
select *
  from openrowset(bulk n'd:\test-csv.csv'
      , formatfile = n'd:\test-csv.fmt'
      , firstrow=1 
      , format='csv'
      ) as eg;
```

As Alex K. mentioned, using `HDR=NO` will help when using a connection string to a source without a header row.

```
select * 
  from openrowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
    , 'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\test.xls;HDR=No'
    , 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
    ) as eg.
```

Comment: First, I am not doing it in "BULK", as I do not have a format file, so not sure I can use the "FIRSTROW" option. I can try the second method and see what happens.  Thanks